# attrs - how to validate an instance of a Literal or None

Tags: python, python-attrs

This is what I have. I believe there are two problems here - the Literal and the None.

```
from attrs import frozen, field
from attrs.validators import instance_of

OK_ARGS = ['a', 'b']

@field
class MyClass:
    my_field: Literal[OK_ARGS] | None = field(validator=instance_of((Literal[OK_ARGS], None)))
```

Error:

```
TypeError: Subscripted generics cannot be used with class and instance checks
```

Edit: I've made a workaround with a custom validator. Not that pretty however:

```
def _validator_literal_or_none(literal_type):
    def inner(instance, attribute, value):
        if (isinstance(value, str) and (value in literal_type)) or (value is None):
            pass
        else:
            raise ValueError(f'You need to provide a None, or a string in this list: {literal_type}')
    return inner
```

Comment: you can try using `typing.Optional` because `None` is not a type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can’t do `isinstance()` checks on Literals/Nones and that’s what the `is_instance` Validator is using internally (it predates those typing features by far).

While we’ve resisted adding a complete implementation of the typing language due to its complexity, having one dedicated to such cases mind be worth exploring if you’d like to open an issue.

Comment: Thank you. I'm probably not the right person to be able to amend the feature. Slightly related question...how do I test against `None` in  the built-in validator instance_of()...?

Comment: oh I re-read your answer. So Nones don't work either?

Comment: Yeah None is super weird.  Take this with a grain of salt because I’m at a beach on my phone (pun intended), but for is_instance you’d need `NoneType` which IIRC you can only get using `tupe(None)`. Python’s types and the new type hint syntax (` | None`) collide here a little bit.

Comment: As for your other question: what you really want is `attrs.validators.optional(attrs.validators.in_(OK_ARGS))`